# How can I see what the "unresolvable conflicts" are when renaming something in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, refactoring, rename

I'm trying to rename a C# namespace in Visual Studio 2015, and after a moment Visual Studio helpfully (?) tells me there are 216 unresolvable conflicts.

That's all the information it seems to provide, though.

How can I see what these conflicts actually are?

The preview button doesn't show anything obvious.

Comment: Im guessing it would cause a name clash, so if you cancel, you should be able to search for those 216 items already with that name?

Comment: Already with which name? I'm renaming a namespace... it's fine if it has the same name as another (and in fact that's what I want). Also, there's tons of things in both namespaces, and any of them could be clashing... it's not that this is exactly unexpected. I'd just like to find out what these 216 things are. Presumably Visual Studio knows, if it's coounted them.

Comment: I wonder if its just not handling namespace changes well so its reporting the 216 items its found in that originating namespace? as you say, it counted something it would be nice if you could find what they are

Comment: Fingers crossed there is a solution that will let us do more than just wonder.

Comment: Aye, I tried it on a number of my apps that I was prepared to rescue if it all went really wrong, but all were able to change, which was weird

Comment: @BugFinder In my case, it was the reason for the refactoring: the method I had started writing already existed.  Since the existing method was not meaningfully named. that was what got changed.  VS couldn't resolve the uncompiling bit I had started writing but abandoned to do the rename.   Based on my and epsilon's experience, it *seems* like you can just run the rename confidently and then do an entire solution search for any remaining use of the terms you wanted changed. hth

Answer (score 3):

I have spent a lot of time but concluded that there is no way to see the conflicts but in all of the encounters I found out that it is because of one of the [Documentation Comments Tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/recommended-tags-for-documentation-comments). The *rename* somehow is unable to rename values inside these tags.